# How to cast simple pointer to a multidimensional-array of fixed size?

Tags: c++, c, casting, multidimensional-array, matrix

I have a function that takes a pointer to a floating point array.  Based on other conditions, I know that pointer is actually pointing to a 2x2 OR 3x3 matrix. (in fact the memory was initially allocated as such, e.g. float M[2][2] )  The important thing is I want to make this determination in the function body, not as the function argument.

```
void calcMatrix( int face, float * matrixReturnAsArray )
{
    // Here, I would much rather work in natural matrix notation
    if( is2x2 )
    {
        // ### cast matrixReturnAsArray to somethingAsMatrix[2][2]
        somethingAsMatrix[0][1] = 2.002;
        // etc..
    }
    else if(is3x3)
    { //etc...
    }

}
```

I am aware that I could use templates and other techniques to better address this problem.  My question is really about how to make such a cast at the ### comment. Working in C++.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem (i.e. "how to cast?" is *rarely* the right problem). I wrote a simple solution to the problem of "how to use multi-dimensional arrays easily?" once: http://ideone.com/gytw7

Comment: There is no way a `float *` points to a multidimensional *anything* (barring really terrible casting that you shouldn't be doing and I'd be surprised if a compiler let you). A `float *` points to a float, which might be the first value in a single-dimensional float array. But it does not point to any sub-array, as you would need for a multidimensional array. 2x2 and 3x3 are both 2D, so both could be a `float **`. Really, though, you'd be much better off creating (or finding) and using a dedicated `Matrix` class.

Comment: Ok, I could change my input argument to float **.  But are you saying that in the case float aMDarray[3][3], the storage of elements is not guaranteed to be continuous?

Comment: @DragoonWraith: Sorry, but you are wrong.  `float a[2][2];` is not compatible with `float**`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, you're right; they're not and I misspoke. I meant more that `float *` cannot be more than unidimensional and `float **` is needed for two dimensions.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: That's still wrong, though.  `float a[2][2];` is a still a single sequence of `float` stored contiguously, but with compiler-provided two-dimensional address calculation.  You can then write `float* p = &a[0][0];` and do the index calculation yourself.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ah, then I simply misunderstood entirely. My apologies. Thanks for the clarification, +1 on both. (Is it better to delete the comment, or not? Not sure of SO-tiquette here)

Comment: Related: [Convert pointer to two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41701239) / [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052818)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
float (*somethingAsMatrix)[2] = (float (*)[2]) matrixReturnAsArray;
```

Comment: Thank you. This certainly works now. I'm just clarifying if I have a misconception about the guaranteed contiguous arrangement of elements in the declaration case float aMDarray[3][3];

Comment: @NoahR: That's contiguous, and compatible with the usage you suggest.

Comment: I tried this technique and the Mac OS X C++ compiler said `error: assigning to 'double (*)[LDN]' from incompatible type 'double (*)[LDN]'`.  Notice the two reported types are the same!  So why are they not assignable?  My code looks like this `double (*F)[LDN]; F=(double (*)[LDN])AF;`  I also tried initializing in the declaration and got a similar error message.

Comment: @Jason perhaps your compiler is broken? If you can provide the full code that you're having trouble with then it'd be worth asking a separate question.

Comment: Why does this work ? Is there a clear documentation about this cast and the types mixing pointers and arrays notation ? Thx

Comment: @ZachB I am talking about the right term of the equality (matricReturnAsArray) not the left term which is clearly a declaration.

Comment: @Hugo this is documented in the C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011): 6.5.4 says that a *cast-expression* is a *unary-expression* preceded by any number of parenthesized *type-name*s, and 6.7.7 says that a *type-name* is "syntactically a declaration for a function or an object of that type that omits the identifier". (So from `float (*somethingAsMatrix)[2]` we can remove the identifier `somethingAsMatrix` to get the *type-name* `float (*)[2]`.)

Comment: Thanks @ecatmur that is very clear.  Nevertheless my next question is : what do you call this type-name float (*identifier)[2] ?
Is it a pointer to 2-sized-arrays of float ie a pointer to a space full of 2-sized-float-arrays ?

Comment: @Hugo yes, that's right - [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/?q=float+%28*identifier%29%5B2%5D) says "declare identifier as pointer to array 2 of float".

Answer (score 9):

`float *` could point to the first element of an array of floats, and ought to be reinterpret_castable to that array type. And the result of that cast could point to the first element of a `float [][]` and so should be reinterpret_castable to that type, and so on. You ought to be able to compose such casts and just directly do

```
float (&arr)[2][2] = *reinterpret_cast<float (*)[2][2]>(matrixReturnAsArray);
```

An argument of the type `float **` is not the same and should not be used this way.

To avoid undefined behavior the pointer must originate from an actual multi-dimensional array, and if the `float*` is used directly you cannot access more than the first row of the multi-dimensional matrix.

```
void foo(float *f) {
    f[3] = 10.;

    float (&arr)[2][2] = *reinterpret_cast<float (*)[2][2]>(f);
    arr[1][1] = 10.;
}

void main() {
    float a[2][2];
    foo(&a[0][0]); // f[3] = 10.; is undefined behavior, arr[1][1] = 10. is well defined

    float b[4];
    foo(&b[0]); // f[3] = 10.; is well-defined behavior, arr[1][1] = 10. is undefined
}
```

Given `float arr[2][2];` nothing guarantees that `&arr[0][1] + 1` is the same as `&arr[1][0]`, as far as I have been able to determine. So although you can use a single dimensional array as a multi-dimensional array by doing `f[i*width + j]` you cannot treat a multi-dimensional array like a single dimensional array.

It's better to use C++'s compile-time type-safety instead of just relying on not accidentally passing the wrong thing or performing the wrong reinterpret_cast. To get type-safety using raw-arrays you should use references to the raw array type you want:

```
void foo(float (&f)[2][2]) {}
void foo(float (&f)[3][3]) {}
```

If you want to pass arrays by value you can't use raw arrays and should instead use something like std::array:

```
void foo(std::array<std::array<float,2>,2> f) {}
void foo(std::array<std::array<float,3>,3> f) {}
```

Comment: Isn't `sizeof (T [N])` guaranteed to be exactly `N * sizeof (T)`?

Comment: I'm aware of a non-normative note in the standard that mentions that. If you can find anything normative please let me know.

Comment: 5.3.3p2 directly states that it is required.  Looks normative to me (not inside a "Note")

Comment: "When applied to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an array of n elements is n times the size of an element." The issue is that I don't see anything that actually prohibits an array from containing extra space at the end. It's said to be 'implied' but I don't see how.

Comment: relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.c++/jpCa0W_wLdI%5B1-25%5D

Comment: If nothing else, that line prohibits padding at the end of an array, because that line is normative.

Comment: If there's nothing else that actually implies what that line says is implied then I would not regard it as a normative statement, I would regard it only as a factually incorrect statement and a bug in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of casting is always cleaner, and easier to deal with, with a judicious use of typedef:

```
typedef float Matrix_t[2][2];

Matrix_t* someThingAsMatrix = (Matrix_t*) matrixReturnAsArray;
```

If this is C++ and not C, though, you should create a matrix class.  (Or better yet, look for an open source one.)

Comment: Use someThingAsMatrix[1][1] = 2.0f; gives:

Incompatible types in assignment of 'float' to 'float [2]'

Comment: Typedef is still helpful, but you need:  `typedef float MatrixRow[2]; MatrixRow* someThingAsMatrix = (MatrixRow*) matrixReturnAsArray;` which is equivalent to ecatmur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right:

```
typedef float Matrix_t[2][2];  
Matrix_t &matrix = *(Matrix_t *)matrixReturnAsArray;
```

or

```
float (&matrix2)[2][2] = *(float ( *)[2][2])matrixReturnAsArray;
```

In C there is only the way with the pointer

```
Matrix_t *someThingAsMatrix = (Matrix_t *)matrixReturnAsArray;
```

and access via:

```
(*someThingAsMatrix)[1][0] = ...
```