# Sending an integer array over UDP in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, visual-c++, casting

I'm trying to send an integer array of size 480X640 to another machine over UDP using winsock programming in C++. I can typecast the array to char * before sending, but i can't figure out how to cast the char * back to integer array. The code segment looks like this:

```
int arrayData[480][640];    
char * arrayChar;

arrayChar = (char *)&arrayData;

// send it to the other end over UDP

// at the other end, receive and convert char * to integer array
```

Is this typecast valid? If anyone could help me with converting 'arrayChar' back to integer array, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) and then cast it back at receiver side using same.

Answer (score 0):

Answers.

1. You don't need the & and it's better to use the right kind of cast in C++.

   char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(arrayData);
2. For the cast you need see ([How to cast simple pointer to a multidimensional-array of fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869056/how-to-cast-simple-pointer-to-a-multidimensional-array-of-fixed-size))
3. You've got over 1MB of data there, which is a lot of packets. Are you really sure you want to use UDP, which does not guarantee packets arrive in order (or at all)?

Comment: This code segment deals with a real time communication..hence UDP is preferred..but i take your point concerning packet losses..will try TCP too! thanks..