# Convert pointer to two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Given is this function

```
void printMatrix(int *m, int ze, int sp)
```

Now *m is supposed to be a 2 dimensional array (or more like a pointer to a 2 dimensional array).

So how can I use this `*m` as `m[][]` ?

Comment: Can you show an example of initializing the value that will be passed in to m? It's unclear whether you created an actual 2-D array and badly forced it to be interpreted as a 1-D array, or if you actually have a 1-D array that you want to process as a 2-D array.

Comment: Can you change the function signature? If so, use a VLA.

Answer (score 4):

Variable-Length Arrays can help you here:

```
int (*p)[sp] = (void*) m;
```

Now you can access the elements via `p[i][j]`.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10f5abc23f045e74)

About the well-definedness of the cast with respect to strict aliasing rules: it is valid, because both `m` and `p` point to compatible types.

Comment: Wouldn't it violate the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @EugeneSh. From what I find on cppreference, it is valid. Maybe I'll dig into a copy of the standard later.

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine. `p` is a pointer to array of integers (though the syntax might be confusing), which is surely compatible with a pointer to array of integers :) *Update* No..wait. Something is not right here.. let me digest it...

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, sorry :) My doubt was about what would `p[i]` point to. Apparently it would point to the `i`th "row" `*(p + sp*sizeof(int))`

Comment: @EugeneSh. exactly. That's where VLAs bring the magic in, to have pointers arithmetics with dynamic stride :)

Comment: `int(*)[n]` and `int*` are not compatible types, that's not why this is ok. But I believe a pointer-to-type can always be coverted to an array-pointer-to-type without violating strict aliasing. "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types:" /--/ "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members". An int array is an aggregate and it includes int among its members.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this doesn't work using the TinyCC compiler, though, most annoyingly it doesn't seem to emit a warning or error :(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, as `m` can be dereferenced only once. But if you know the dimensions of the array, you can calculate the 1D index as

```
element[i][j]=m[i * width + j];
```

Comment: Actually, the computation would make more sense as `element[i][j]=m[i * width + j];`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! :)

Comment: Why not simply use memcpy so that you utilize the data cache optimally? This code may or may not do that.

Comment: @Lundin I think `=` means "is expressed as" here, not an actual copy to a new array.

Comment: Oh that... Right, @Quentin, that's what is meant here.

Answer (score 2):

If `m` is indeed a pointer to a 2D matrix, you can declare the arguments this way:

```
void printMatrix(int rows, int cols, int m[rows][cols]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assume that it is a so-called "mangled" array. In which case you can create a new array as a VLA:

```
void printMatrix(int *m, int ze, int sp)
{
  int array[ze][sp];
  memcpy(array, m, sizeof(int[ze][sp]));
}
```

Or perhaps as a dynamically allocated 2D array:

```
void printMatrix(int *m, int ze, int sp)
{
  size_t size = sizeof(int[ze][sp]);
  int (*array)[sp] = malloc(size);
  memcpy(array, m, size);
  ...
}
```

Converting the `int*` to an array pointer type is however questionable practice, which will cause pointer aliasing problems. The best is of course if you can rewrite the function prototype to properly use a 2D array instead.

Comment: Ok, this is a good answer too (and seems in relation to my topic the most fitting one). Thanks, will try that too

Comment: What do you define "mangled array" as? A multidimensional array hidden behind a pointer to its first element?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, something like that was often used in older C programs, since they didn't have pointers to VLAs. Typically you would do `int* array = malloc(x*y*sizeof(int))`

Comment: Thanks, Google wasn't helpful on this one :)