# Numpy Like Arrays for C

Tags: c, numpy

In numpy, you can access the size and shape of the array with `array.size` and `array.shape` while elements can be accessed using `array[i]`.

How does one achieve this with a C structure? One can do something like

```
struct{
    int size;
    int shape[2];
    int *elements;
} int_array;
```

but then elements can be  accessed as

```
int_array.elements[i].
```

not like numpy.

How can I have an array that stores size and shape, but whose elements can be accessed in the usual way using []?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Should be possible with appropriate (local) VLA typedef (and type cast or helper variable of that type).

Comment: If C++ is an option, [check out `xtensor`](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor)

Answer (score 2):

1. Allocate an array that is 3 cells bigger than you need.
2. Put size and shape in the first 3 cells
3. Increment the pointer by `3 *
   sizeof(int)`.
4. Write accessors for size and shape.

You can then access the array in the usual way.

Don't forget to subtract `3 * sizeof(int)` from the pointer before you free it.

Comment: well this works only directly for arrays where the element types are big enough to hold the dimensions...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple macro to cast your pointer to a 2D array ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11869056/102441)):

```
#define INDEX(a) ((int(*)[a.shape[1]]) a.elements)
```

Which you can use as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int size;
    int shape[2];
    int *elements;
} int_array;


int main() {
    int_array arr;
    arr.shape[0] = 2;
    arr.shape[1] = 3;
    arr.elements = malloc(6*sizeof(*arr.elements));

    INDEX(arr)[0][1] = 2;

    printf("%d", INDEX(arr)[0][1]);
}
```