# cudaMallocManaged for 2D and 3D array

Tags: cuda

If one wants to copy the arrays to device from host one does **cudamalloc** and **cudaMemcpy**. But to lessen the hassle one just does cudaMallocManaged without the former two things and life was never simpler before.
The code looks like this(more or less)

```
__global__ void convert(float kelvin[], float celsius[])  //can pass 
arrays in kernel
{
     int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i<N)
    kelvin[i]=celsius[i]+273.15;
}

int main()
{
    float *celsius =(float *)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *kelvin =(float *)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&celsius, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&kelvin, N*sizeof(float));

// init celsius here

dim3 blocksPerGrid(1,1,1); //use only one block
dim3 threadsPerBlock(N,1,1); //use N threads in the block
convert<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(kelvin,celsius);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

//Doing stuff with the output here

return 0;
}
```

The previous example seems clear to me. **But, how to do** **cudaMallocManaged for 2D and 3D array**? I've been trying

```
__global__ void MatAdd(float A[N][N], float B[N][N], float C[N][N])
{
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
if (i < N && j < N)
C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
}

int main()
{   // I thonk, 2D arrays can be passed as pointer to pointers
    float **A = (float **)malloc(N*N*sizeof(float));
    float **B = (float **)malloc(N*N*sizeof(float));
    float **C = (float **)malloc(N*N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&A, N*N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&B, N*N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&C, N*N*sizeof(float));


A[N][N]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
B[N][N]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
dim3 threadsPerBlock(16, 16);
dim3 numBlocks(N / threadsPerBlock.x, N / threadsPerBlock.y);
MatAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(A, B, C);
//outputs and all

}
```

But, It shows the following error

```
matrix_add.cu(22): error: too many initializer values

matrix_add.cu(25): error: argument of type "float **" is incompatible with parameter of type "float (*)[3]"
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "2D arrays"  can't be passed as pointer to pointers. And why is everything allocated twice?

Comment: @talonmies , as I have allocated memory in CPU I'll have to allocate it in cuda device also. Here the cudaMallocManaged allocates same memory in GPU. At least I think so

Comment: You think wrongly. The malloc calls are unnecessary and incorrect, as is literally everything else in your code. I recommend you re-read everything in the answer to your last question, because you clearly didn't understand what you were told there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a lot wrong in your attempt, so much that it was faster to write a working version than list out all the individual problems in the code in your question. So here is a working version of what it appears you were trying to do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

const int N = 3;

__global__ void MatAdd(float A[][N], float B[][N], float C[][N])
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (i < N && j < N)
        C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    float* A; cudaMallocManaged(&A, N*N*sizeof(float));
    float* B; cudaMallocManaged(&B, N*N*sizeof(float));
    float* C; cudaMallocManaged(&C, N*N*sizeof(float));

    const float A_vals[N][N]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    const float B_vals[N][N]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    float (*C_vals)[N] = reinterpret_cast<float (*)[N]>(C);

    std::copy(&A_vals[0][0], &A_vals[0][0] + N*N, A);
    std::copy(&B_vals[0][0], &B_vals[0][0] + N*N, B);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(16, 16);
    dim3 numBlocks(1, 1);
    MatAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>( reinterpret_cast<float (*)[N]>(A),
                                            reinterpret_cast<float (*)[N]>(B),
                                            C_vals );

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            std::cout << C_vals[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Some important points:

1. Managed memory allocation replaces standard host memory allocation and produces memory which is directly accessible on both the host and the device.
2. All arrays decay to a pointer when passed as arguments to a function by value. That decay is not recursive. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/681865) for more details.
3. You can (and will need to) cast in order to use the `[][]` access syntax on linear memory allocated dynamically at runtime (this applies to `malloc`, `new`, or any of the CUDA host memory allocation APIs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11869056/681865) for more details).
4. Initialization syntax and assignment syntax for arrays are not interchangeable.

All I can suggest is that you study it thoroughly until you understand how it works.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your elaborated answer regarding this question. I surely don't have much of a knowledge when it comes to the memory allocation part of the program. I am a Physics major student and a python programmer so my path doesn't cross with the memory elements. This summer I picked up CUDA for my simulation project and did some huge mistakes along the way. Nevertheless, there is always a learning curve.