# C++ Multidimensional array in existing memory

Tags: c++, arrays

(This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869056/how-to-cast-simple-pointer-to-a-multidimensional-array-of-fixed-size) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) that refer to fixed sizes, the issue is not to understand how pointers are stored, but if the compiler can automate the manual function).

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory) multidimensional arrays are stored sequentially.

```
// These arrays are the same
int array1[3][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}; 
int array2[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

However I'm trying to create a 2 dimension array of floats in pre-allocated memory:

```
float a[5][10] 
float b[50]; // should be same memory
```

Then I'm trying:

```
vector<char> x(1000);
float** a = (float**)x.data();
a[0][1] = 5;
```

The above code crashes, obviously because the compiler does not know the size of the array to allocate it in memory like in the compiler-level known array in the first example.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to allocate a multi dimensional array in sequential memory without manually calculating the pointers (say, by manually shifting the index and calling placement new for example)?

Currently, I'm doing it manually, for example:

```
template <typename T> size_t CreateBuffersInMemory(char* p,int n,int BufferSize)
{
    // ib = T** to store the data
    int ty = sizeof(T);

    int ReqArraysBytes = n * sizeof(void*);
    int ReqT = ReqArraysBytes * (ty*BufferSize);
    if (!p)
        return ReqT;

    memset(p, 0, ReqT);
    ib = (T**)p;
    p += n * sizeof(void*);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ib[i] = (T*)p;
        p += ty*BufferSize;
    }
    return ReqT;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes OK, but can I have the compiler initialize the array automatically as it does with static arrays?

Comment: The syntax of accessing `float**` is the same: `a[i][j]` but the semantics of accessing a true multidimensional array is entirely different. `float**` is a pointer to a pointer. So the first dimension should contain pointers to the rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: @rustyx: I don't think it's exactly a duplicate, but understanding how `float**` vs. `float [][]` works might help in answering the question. Maybe you could simply refer to the post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast simple pointer to a multidimensional-array of fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869056/how-to-cast-simple-pointer-to-a-multidimensional-array-of-fixed-size)

Comment: ***but if the compiler can automate the manual function*** The answer is it can't outside of what https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594599/487892 does.

Answer (score 3):

To allocate `T[rows][cols]` array as a one-dimensional array allocate `T[rows * cols]`.

To access element `[i][j]` of that one-dimensional array you can do `p[i * cols + j]`.

Example:

```
template<class T>
struct Array2d {
    T* elements_;
    unsigned columns_;

    Array2d(unsigned rows, unsigned columns)
        : elements_(new T[rows * columns]{}) // Allocate and value-initialize.
        , columns_(columns)
    {}

    T* operator[](unsigned row) {
        return elements_ + row * columns_;
    }

    // TODO: Implement the special member functions.
};

int main() {
    Array2d<int> a(5, 10);
    a[3][1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This would work but the existing code will access the element [i][j] by p[i][j], not by [i*n + j].

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Added an example for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes undefined behavior because `x.data()` does not point to an array of pointers but to an array of 1000 objects of type `char`. You should be thankful that it crashes… ;-)

One way to access a contiguous buffer of some type as if it was a multidimensional array is to have another object that represents a multidimensional view into this buffer. This view object can then, e.g., provide member functions to access the data using a multidimensional index. To enable the `a[i][j][k]` kind of syntax (which you seem to be aiming for), provide an overloaded `[]` operator which returns a proxy object that itself offers an `operator []` and so on until you get down to a single dimension.

For example, for the case that dimensions are fixed at compile time, we can define

```
template <int Extent, int... Extents>
struct row_major_layout;

template <int Extent>
struct row_major_layout<Extent>
{
    template <typename T>
    static auto view(T* data) { return data; }
};

template <int Extent, int... Extents>
struct row_major_layout
{
    static constexpr int stride = (Extents * ... * 1);

    template <typename T>
    class span
    {
        T* data;

    public:
        span(T* data) : data(data) {}

        auto operator[](std::size_t i) const
        {
            return row_major_layout<Extents...>::view(data + i * stride);
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    static auto view(T* data) { return span<T>(data); }
};
```

and then simply create and access such a `row_major_layout` view

```
void test()
{
    constexpr int M = 7, N = 2, K = 5;

    std::vector<int> bla(row_major_layout<M, N, K>::size);

    auto a3d = row_major_layout<M, N, K>::view(data(bla));

    a3d[2][1][3] = 42;
}
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwskEF0WAGYbsHAAwBBOQqUrM6rSIJ4GhAJ7Gzli54KYAtgAOzL72mgoEqtgAHr4sBKSq4QB0KZExmHGCHha6xCLIEcSoAO4A%2Bn5MVCSlzK6iBBp83ha%2BgcF2GmFxabENsiY5BHkFqkVlFVXENUx1jp3RvdmWAOxN5qobqq1BTCGdBK4BGUx%2BdgAqS5uqurt4yKpMjqiqAG54mMUQZwBUqui7TAAlOpVqNMAQxCw/gDGiCACKeDjLBGyNY%2Bfw7PZacI9DLxRJxFJJXGZJa5fKFErlSrVWr1RGrTxXG5Oe5oFi6TBRALEAkRQR4ABeHVkcNUEAWeNUvyJ0pJBEEgMaTM2LLuqnZnO5vJxuTwag0Yol6Uyctlv1oStRiIsV227VCByOLBO50umyUTEEgmuAVYKo2SLWVyuP2hBCYyua602AREACMXMgQAGQ4I/Swvr9/hHgSBw0wIDmgSC%2BMibTGQw8nqpUEdiLsSBwAKx8ZtwiC6dAgEAC4WlCJ4YGahq2qul1PjsEQ4hQsbUybTWZ9TSSzJE4w9t4fIsA9S8RJyvVYK3B8dIhFjwPl63Ru0Yh37Q7HU6qC79VNq%2B6PIivd6fMNi2BINp0hX1/S0d9sF3XNYQvBkUTRaMrEUZQDS0F5MAKJsP2jF5UH1LZMF0CAlW8Rkrw1VAOV8bU%2BVUABZewxWWBIADlmNULgEgAaU45soy8Strj0LcsKIYhOnCYxVETQt5wmWkZnpLQGPY3jN17IVMFPCsrh/Z4mFkdBOIUmkpjpOZVPU1QeM07dPmLCA5MBXS702Iz0BbHguBbBFW1oPzvNkPzOIAFl828VkvcwpEBRhpGbKRSBYaRTGS1BpE0fh%2BGuURxA6LhZFoZKCDSuL4oAaxAAA2ZskloLhTAADlkGrTGbMLmpqmr6AYaQwuS1KpHS0hMqkZLBBAUxSDKka4tIOBYCQNBAmcTAyAoCBVoCdbiBQZg2AHPIWEq0gDGcXxiCm5zytIeMFCYYhXGkErSFW044gAeRYBgXvm0gsAqNgGEkAH8GIcS8EwqaAa5LDHDBt7wkwfqAZceMG2ezQMCR0riDwPxXoWw72By3hGDweMpsgeK6ycajYYAWi7Q1OF4fhaGWVQma%2B2RJvyiQ6HitGkpSu7xqibqmZqsKNVJ8UhhEU7gQlfAJP3YqEhxtbQd5ORLVUbKOd4Urytc0hqtkMKkma5YAE5aBq2R7bC5taFkF2EqkQbxYB8bJum2bzZF6QuGSonaFMGbhtGgPg/mi3MOuvBqJAMKgA%3D%3D%3D)

Or in case the array bounds are dynamic:

```
template <int D>
class row_major_layout;

template <>
class row_major_layout<1>
{
public:
    row_major_layout(std::size_t extent) {}

    static constexpr std::size_t size(std::size_t extent)
    {
        return extent;
    }

    template <typename T>
    friend auto view(T* data, const row_major_layout&)
    {
        return data;
    }
};

template <int D>
class row_major_layout : row_major_layout<D - 1>
{
    std::size_t stride;

public:
    template <typename... Dim>
    row_major_layout(std::size_t extent, Dim&&... extents)
        : row_major_layout<D - 1>(std::forward<Dim>(extents)...), stride((extents * ... * 1))
    {
    }

    template <typename... Dim>
    static constexpr std::size_t size(std::size_t extent, Dim&&... extents)
    {
        return extent * row_major_layout<D - 1>::size(std::forward<Dim>(extents)...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    class span
    {
        T* data;
        std::size_t stride;
        const row_major_layout<D - 1>& layout;

    public:
        span(T* data, std::size_t stride, const row_major_layout<D - 1>& layout)
            : data(data), stride(stride), layout(layout)
        {
        }

        auto operator[](std::size_t i) const
        {
            return view(data + i * stride, layout);
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    friend auto view(T* data, const row_major_layout& layout)
    {
        return span<T>(data, layout.stride, layout);
    }
};
```

and

```
void test(int M, int N, int K)
{
    std::vector<int> bla(row_major_layout<3>::size(M, N, K));

    auto a3d = view(data(bla), row_major_layout<3>(M, N, K));

    a3d[2][1][3] = 42;
}
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwskEF0WAGYbsHAAwBBOQqUrM6rSIJ4GhAJ7Gzli54KYAtgAOzL72mgoEqgAiHhZKTIKCqsSoAO4A%2Bn5MVCRpzK6iBBp83ha%2BgcF2Gpox5nEJSakZWTl5BVW0NRwA7MXmASIARi7IIJ6q4w3pmdnEuUz5jhC66CAggngAXphpEZgAHr4sBACU6j3d0SXmE6q6TE7IqmgsuvsBxLd6q%2BtbO7ebmCWXzWAL%2B%2B0OJzGE26vRuN2ImAIYhYqnBmCORSh4wunixqjKQXulS0BFcAXRTD8dgAKjUbgZiHh0ehVExHKhVAA3JkpCDUgBUqnQ9yYpCeqBeEWSU2as1ajm4ADZjniYXj4YjkUKRZiLDccd4utFZL0fP5CSEquEojU6olpU0ZnMFhEQJNHS15m0tJFVABaVQdWQmQ2wibLb6giK6RlYXVePqDYajPUTAkVUKk8ksSmYAB0BaieD8dImDumnpdQJWIN%2BuwO6IIYsixaVSoLedRDaOghVqbhqjd5dlzu9ml9AaD2GrqwMJBSTGI6CqLZLwYgaJ7xw7xzFMbwWCgm4IiUFHdUgtoxz712h537Z0uCZu6aJmbJFKp59XpfGdwe4qSm8HwRrW2zRgCM5gWC3ZNkWJZcIq7aFsevaqvet4DgiSLECix4Xu6FZyl6Co%2Bv6gbGJGWxQXOxALkuK6tuuqHbgWKomuhT54q%2Blokh%2BOZUqotLBnidq3AErDoWGA4CtqBBMPGA5/sCPzgZ8saYIpSnPLohEjvKhRkZOHiIaoBnxni/RDHgIzquGEksHygrCvJe4qVG6kHpgYo6VKjREaOpHjuRU5KmZJGQg%2BSmDnJTAQC5TC7p5h77lgSUGRABk3tFapRXeXF5eMbJEKoqDksQ9wkBwACsfDVZEUGqX8eCnL5dnYhh0UajhKLcpgvIJeovCqHgBGpd54Uuux0lwgamGPhZD48cSmhZp%2BNK/qoDJMiwLLFRyfW8rJCU%2BRKunDk65mmVlUntUkmq4eJklaMJ04nZNBR5uNYo3RxD5zTif0JriXDyIoyhqFUnKYMgRDEJ0FicqgB74pgugQNaACyYrWgAcjjRyqAA0jeuXzaB0Ow1VWjhMYqhDHFF2VmOsiUWBEDY6o%2BPE9ei3zftrKyCyGi%2Bod8UihADNJUzxEulUrPrpz3Mk9NuIPkwQs1TwXA1dEtUdPVWus/V9i%2BgALDrQNzVIu4MNI1VSKQLDSKYjuoNI1S8PwtyiOIlSg7QjsEC7Nu7gA1iAirVXmtBcKYAAcsiKqY1Vm/HiqKvQdtSGbjvO1IrukO7UiO4IICmKQwcFzbpBwLASBoIEziYGQFAQI3ATN8QKDMGwOzECILBh6QBjOL4xBl5LIekAMCiLq40iB6QjdUkcADyLAMAv1ekFgmRsAwkg7/gCKw3g0Nlzv%2Bww44R9L%2BEmDZ4XLgDBVxCuJoGB30HjJ%2BIvNe93YPwfgjA8ADDLpAXcZUnBnWkH6ZYItOBe14LQLo/o16yFLr7CQdBbb2zztPYuex05%2BkVGbJ4gDVAQAIAPIepwIC4EICQIash6CqE/k3Q%2BHw5BXnYcA3gQcQ7XlIBHWQZs8zxy6AATloIqWQUizbVVoLIeRjBpC5ydoQ6Qpdy6VyEXgqQXBHZ/1oKYCu%2BdC7F0EdXYR0MJ54AlCAM2QA%3D%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869576/8769985) assuming you want an array of `char` you can do something like

```
std::vector<char> x(1000);
char (&ar)[200][5] = *reinterpret_cast<char (*)[200][5]>(x.data());
```

Then you can use `ar` as a normal two-dimensional array, like

```
char c = ar[2][3];
```

Comment: One thing about this approach is the 2D array must be a fixed size at compile time since you need to cast it to a fixed type. This will not be as flexible as a matrix class.

Comment: I think the above code has undefined behavior. A pointer to an array and a pointer to its first element are not [pointer interconvertible](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-4). Furthermore, at least as soon as the element type of the array that `ar` refers to would be anything other than `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte`, I would also believe the [strict aliasing rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) violated here. I don't think anyone should be doing this…

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to achieve the same, I 've created a variadit template function that would create a n-dimension array in existing memory:

```
template <typename T = char> size_t CreateArrayAtMemory(void*, size_t bs)
{
    return bs*sizeof(T);
}

template <typename T = char,typename ... Args>
size_t CreateArrayAtMemory(void* p, size_t bs, Args ... args)
{
    size_t R = 0;
    size_t PS = sizeof(void*);
    char* P = (char*)p;
    char* P0 = (char*)p;

    size_t BytesForAllPointers = bs*PS;
    R = BytesForAllPointers;

    char* pos = P0 + BytesForAllPointers;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bs; i++)
    {
        char** pp = (char**)P;
        if (p)
            *pp = pos;
        size_t RLD = CreateArrayAtMemory<T>(p ? pos : nullptr, args ...);
        P += PS;
        R += RLD;
        pos += RLD;
    }
    return R;
}
```

Usage:

Create a 2x3x4 char array:

```
int j = 0;
size_t n3 = CreateArrayAtMemory<char>(nullptr,2,3,4);
std::vector<char> a3(n3);
char*** f3 = (char***)a3.data();
CreateArrayAtMemory<char>(f3,2,3,4);
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 2; i1++)
{
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 3; i2++)
    {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 4; i3++)
        {
            f3[i1][i2][i3] = j++;
        }
    }
}
```