# Initializing large 2-dimensional array to all one value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to initialize a large 2-dimensional array (say 1000x1000, though I'd like to go even larger) to all `-1` in C++.

If my array were 1-dimensional, I know I could do:

```
int my_array[1000];
memset(my_array, -1, sizeof(my_array));
```

However, `memset` does not allow for initializing all the elements of an array to be another array. I know I could just make a 1-dimensional array of length 1000000, but for readability's sake I would prefer a 2-dimensional array. I could also just loop through the 2-dimensional array to set the values after initializing it to all `0`, but this bit of code will be run many times in my program and I'm not sure how fast that would be. What's the best way of achieving this?

Edited to add minimal reproducible example:

```
int my_array[1000][1000];
// I want my_array[i][j] to be -1 for each i, j
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] - the declared 2D array and how would you like to initialize it. If you are concerned about speed, the 2D array can be stored inside the 1D and indexed appropriately.

Comment: Loop throu two dimensions. As long as you don't do anything fancy, your optimizer should optimize this code just fine.

Comment: Note that 1,000,000 `int`s will exceed the available Automatic Storage on a lot of systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little bit surprised.

And I know, it is C++. And, I would never use plain C-Style arrays.

And therefore the accepted answer is maybe the best.

But, if we come back to the question

```
int my_array[1000];
memset(my_array, -1, sizeof(my_array));
```

and

```
int my_array[1000][1000];
// I want my_array[i][j] to be -1 for each i, j
```

Then the easiest and fastest solution is the same as the original assumption:

```
int my_array[1000][1000];
memset(my_array, -1, sizeof(my_array));
```

There is no difference. The compiler will even optimze this away and use fast assembler loop instructions.

Sizeof is smart enough. It will do the trick. And the memory is contiguous: So, it will work. Fast. Easy.

(A good compiler will do the same optimizations for the other solutions).

Please consider.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU GCC you can:

```
int my_array[1000][1000] = { [0 .. 999] = { [0 .. 999] = -1, }, };
```

With any other compiler you need to:

```
int my_array[1000][1000] = { { -1, -1, -1, .. repeat -1 1000 times }, ... repeat { } 1000 times ... };
```

Side note: The following is doing assignment, not initialization:

```
int my_array[1000][1000];
for (auto&& i : my_array) 
    for (auto&& j : i)
        j = -1;
```

> Is there any real difference between doing what you wrote and doing for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){ for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){ my_array[i][j]=-1; } }?

It depends. If you have a bad compiler, you compile without optimization, etc., then yes. Most probably, no. Anyway, don't use indexes. I believe the [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in this case roughly translates to something like this:

```
for (int (*i)[1000]  = my_array; i < my_array + 1000; ++i)
   for (int *j = *i; j < *i + 1000; ++j)
        *j = -1;
```

Side note: Ach! It hurts to calculate `my_array + 1000` and `*i + 1000` each loop. That's like 3 operations done each loop. This cpu time wasted! It can be easily optimized to:

```
for (int (*i)[1000]  = my_array, (*max_i)[1000] = my_array + 10000; i < max_i; ++i)
   for (int *j = *i, *max_j = *i + 1000; j < max_j; ++j)
        *j = -1;
```

The `my_array[i][j]` used in your loop, translates into `*(*(my_array + i) + j)` (see [aarray subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator)). That from pointer arithmetics is equal to `*(*((uintptr_t)my_array + i * sizeof(int**)) + j * sizeof(int*))`. Counting operations, `my_array[i][j]` is behind the scenes doing multiplication, addition, dereference, multiplication, addition, derefence - like six operations. (When using bad or non-optimizing compiler), your version could be way slower.

That said, a good compiler should optimize each version to the same code, as shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/cbjo34).

> And are either of these significantly slower than just initializing it explicitly by typing a million -1's?

I believe assigning each array element (in this particular case of elements having the easy to optimize type `int`) will be as fast or slower then initialization. It really depends on your particular compiler and on your architecture. A bad compiler can do very slow version of iterating over array elements, so it would take forever. On the other hand a static initialization can embed the values in your program, so your program size will increase by `sizeof(int) * 1000 * 1000`, and during program startup is will do plain `memcpy` when initializing static regions for your program. So, when compared to a properly optimized loop with assignment, you will not gain nothing in terms of speed and loose tons of read-only memory.

Comment: Thanks. I've never seen `auto` before. Is there any real difference between doing what you wrote and doing `for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){ for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){ my_array[i][j]=-1; } }`? And are either of these significantly slower than just initializing it explicitly by typing a million `-1`'s?

Answer (score 0):

If the array is static, it's placed in sequential memory (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)). So char [1000][1000] is equal to char [1000000] (if your stack can hold that much).

If the array has been created with multidimensional new (say `char(*x)[5] = new char[5][5]`) then it's also contiguous.

If it's not (if you create it with dynamic allocations), then you can use the solutions found in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593936/c-multidimensional-array-in-existing-memory) to map a n-dimension array to a single one after you have memsetd it.

Comment: What do you mean by *If the array is static, it's placed in sequential memory.*?  All arrays are in contiguous memory.

Comment: He possibly meant possibility of something like this `int *array[1000]`, where every value is initialized to another array.

Comment: @NathanOliver, when you have a dynamic multidimensional array, you can't have it in contiguous memory. `char**  a; a = new char[10] ; for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) a[i] = new char[100];` - Not continuous memory.

Comment: Is it really guaranteed that `char[10][10]` is continuous?

Comment: @Quimby according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That is not a dynamic multidimensional array.  That is just an array of pointers.  A dynamic multidimensional array looks like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29d5a3ad9ad34b56) and is contiguous.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Not really a guarantee, I did not find anything about this in the standard. I don't really expect a compiler to do otherwise, but relying on whether an array is static or not seems dangerous.

Comment: `An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type. The element type shall be complete whenever the array type is specified.` C Standard, 6.2.5, paragraph 20

Comment: @Quimby See [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#1.sentence-6).  That guarantees an array is contiguous and since it is than an array of arrays has all of the sub arrays in contiguous memory.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Regarding your update: `char** x = new char[5][5]` is not legal.  `new char[5][5]` returns a `char(*)[5]`, not a `char**`.