# Casting byte array to multi-dimentional array

Tags: c++, casting

I have a byte array serialized from a stream **char* Buf** which points to an array of 64 bytes.

I wish to cast it into a function input parameter **Foo(char[4][16] Buf)** without copying each and every single bytes.

Any easy for doing so?

Comment: Anything "difficult" you tried so far?

Comment: You could pass it to the function if the underlying data structure is the same. That can be done because you can represent a 2D contiguous data structure as contiguous 1D array. If not you have to iterate through it by calculating the exact positions-

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593936/c-multidimensional-array-in-existing-memory

Comment: If you received that data from a file or via network, copying the 64 bytes is not going to impact the performance of your program noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast any buffer to any array you want:

```
void Foo(char(&buf)[4][16])
{
}

int main()
{
    char* buf = new char[64];
    Foo((char(&)[4][16])(buf));
    delete[] buf;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure cast can be done, but if the underlying structure doesn't meet the expected one, it will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in link given by Michael Chourdakis

```
*reinterpret_cast<char(*)[4][16]>(Buf)
```