# create a pointer to a 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a 
`bool array[size][size]`
and want to pass a pointer of it to a function to change its value.

```
void change_to_true(???, int i, int j) { // don't know what type it should be
  array[i][j] = 1;
}
```

How do I create a pointer of the array, and how should I pass the pointer to the function so
that I can change its value? BTW it's c code.

Thanks

Edit:
I tried

```
static bool array[size][size];
bool (*array_t)[index] = array;
void change_to_true(bool array, int i, int j);
```

Compiler told me `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer`
I tried to change the type definition of the function parameter from `bool array` to `bool* array`, still not work.

I also tried `bool (*array_t)[][size] = &array` and `bool (*array_t)[size][size] = &array;` for the pointer, still not work.

Also since the size of the array is decided during the runtime, I can't have a enum or a global array defined that way.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
void change_to_true(bool** array, int i, int j)
```

Comment: Actually, it's a pointer to a pointer to one or more `bool`s. Arrays devolve to pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I couldn't remember which it was. Maybe my first instinct was correct...I'll change it back.

Comment: No.  Neither `(bool *array[], ...)` nor `(bool **array, ...)` is correct.

Comment: I'm not saying it's correct, I'm saying that's what `bool* array[]` would be if used as a function argument.

Comment: I've removed my original comment; it wasn't accurate enough.  My second comment stands as accurate, I believe.  Produce compiling, running code — by all means crib anything you want from my answer while doing so — to come up with a version that works with `bool *array[]` or `bool **array`...

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple solution — but no pointer to 2D array

The function should be simply:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

enum { size = 24 };

extern void change_to_true(bool array[][size], int i, int j);

void change_to_true(bool array[][size], int i, int j)
{
    array[i][j] = true;
}

int main(void)
{
    bool array[size][size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
             array[i][j] = false;
             change_to_true(array, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming, of course, that you have a C99 or C2011 compiler.  If you're stuck with C89, then you'll have to provide definitions for `bool` and `true`; the rest does not need to change.  I'm not convinced the function call is worth it, compared with the assignment of `false`.

#### Solution using pointer to 2D array

Note that the code above does not, strictly, create a pointer to a 2D array.  If you are really, really sure that's what you want, then the notation changes:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

enum { size = 24 };

extern void change_to_true(bool (*array)[][size], int i, int j);

void change_to_true(bool (*array)[][size], int i, int j)
{
    (*array)[i][j] = true;
}

int main(void)
{
    bool array[size][size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
             array[i][j] = false;
             change_to_true(&array, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

There's no benefit to using a formal 'pointer to array' that I can think of, though — not in this context.

#### Solution using C99 variable length arrays

In C99, you can also use a VLA — variable length array — like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

extern void change_to_true(int size, bool array[][size], int i, int j);

void change_to_true(int size, bool array[][size], int i, int j)
{
    array[i][j] = true;
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int size = 2; size < 10; size++)
    {
        bool array[size][size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = false;
                change_to_true(size, array, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the size must precede the array declaration in the function declaration.  And yes, you also write this with pointer to array notation (actually, I edited the pointer to array notation code first, then realized that I wanted the simpler version).

---

#### Which to use?

Unless you have compelling reasons not mentioned in the question, the first version is the code to use.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array) should answer you question.

In short, you make a pointer to the first element and then pass it around.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] C supports bool since C 99 
Besides that, by declaring it that way, the actual array is a pointer to a memory zone with all the size^2 instances. This means that you can pass array to change it in the function, and in your header declare that you are receiving bool array[][]. 
That way it should work.

Comment: Where have you been this last 13+ years?  C99 introduced `bool`.  (Or, maybe, you should be asking your compiler vendor where it has been for the last 13+ years, if your compiler vendor hasn't caught up to that fact that it is now the 21st Century and no longer 1989.)

Comment: I actually learned that C didn't have bool, and every time I needed it I declare it with enum. 
Looks like I really am 14 years behind. Thanks!