# Pointers equivalent to Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know that If i define an array like

```
int a [10];
```

I can use a pointer notation, to access it's address using `a+<corresponding_item_in_array>`
and it's value using, `*(a+<corresponding_item_in_array>)` .

Now I wanted to reverse things, I used `malloc` to allocate a memory to a integer pointer, and tried to represent the pointer in subscript notation but it didn't work

```
int *output_array;
output_array = (int *) (malloc(2*2*2*sizeof(int))); //i.e, space for 3d array

output_array[0][0][1] = 25;  
// ^ produces error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

I may have used an pointer expression using Storage Mapping, but ain't the simpler method available? and Why?

Comment: You can use the answer at this post to extend to 3rd dimension as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int*` type is *not* an equivalent of the 3D array type; it is an equivalent of a 1D array type:

```
int *output_array;
output_array = (int *) (malloc(8*sizeof(int))); //i.e, space for array of 8 ints
output_array[5] = 25; // This will work
```

The problem with arrays of higher ranks is that in order to index into a 2D, 3D, etc. array the compiler must know the size of each dimension except the first one in order to calculate the offsets from the indexes correctly. To deal with 3D arrays, define a 2D element, like this:

```
typedef int element2d[2][2];
```

Now you can do this:

```
element2d *output_array;
output_array = (element2d*) (malloc(2*sizeof(element2d))); 
output_array[0][0][1] = 25; // This will work now
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Tdjgfi)

Comment: Does tha `malloc`ed, element be on the top, i mean, output_array[malloced][2][2] ?

Comment: Incidentally, you can do it even without the typedef, but the syntax is way more awkward (the declaration would be `int (*outputArray)[2][2];` and the cast would be `(int (*)[2][2])`).

Comment: @cipher Correct, it's on the inside. So if you do `malloc(200*sizeof(element2d))` the highest index would be `outputArray[199][1][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

What's the type of `output_array`? `int *`.

What's the type of `*(output_array+n)` or `output[n]`? `int`.

Is subscript permitted on `int`? Both subscripts (eg. `*(output_array+n)` and `output[n]`) are pointer operations, and `int` is not a pointer. This explains the error you recieved.

You can declare a pointer to `int[x][y]` like this: `int (*array)[x][y];`

You can allocate storage that's a suitable alternative to a 3D array to `array` using: `array = malloc(42 * x * y);`. This would be the equivalent to `int array[42][x][y];`, except that arrays aren't modifiable lvalues, the `alignof`, `sizeof` and address-of operators work differently and the storage duration is different.

Answer (score 0):

Because compiler doesn't have any idea about the size of each dimension, so it's not able to find out where `output_array[0][0][1]` should be.

You could try this

```
typedef int (* array3d)[2][2];
array3d output_array;
output_array = (array3d) malloc(2 * 2 * 2 * sizeof(int));
output_array[0][0][1] = 25;
printf("%d\n", output_array[0][0][1]);
```