# Two dimensional arrays with pointers

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

In the below can someone explain the outputs obtained when executed:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char a[5][10]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
char **str=a;
printf("%p ", &a[0]);
printf("\n%p ", &str[0]);
printf("\n%p ", &str[3]);
printf("\n%p ", &str[1][56]);
printf("\n%p ", &(*(*(str+4)+1)));
}
```

Below is the output observed:

```
0xbf7f6286 
0xbf7f6286 
0xbf7f6292 
0x38 
0x1
```

- &a[0] is the address of the starting address of array
- &str[0] is thesame

  Can some one explain how the address of str[3] is 0xbf7f6292. As per my understanding the &str[0] and &str[3] should differ by 30 bytes.

  Also please someone explain how the output for other two cases also.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your array `a`, even with two dimensions, is not synonymous with a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 9):

**The Very Short Answer**:

Change this:

```
char **str;
```

To be this:

```
char (*str)[10];
```

And fix any errors in your code thereafter. The type of `str` is not compatible with the type of your two dimensional array. I took the liberty of fixing the return type to be `int` for `main()` (void is not allowed per the C standard). I also marked the source where you technically have undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[5][10]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
    char (*str)[10] = a;
    printf("%p ", &a[0]);
    printf("\n%p ", &str[0]);
    printf("\n%p ", &str[3]);
    printf("\n%p ", &str[1][56]);       // this is undefined behaviour
    printf("\n%p ", &(*(*(str+4)+1)));
    return 0;
}
```

You should also note the last `printf()` statement has a superfluous `&(*(...))` that is not needed. It can be stripped to look like this, which is equivalent:

```
    printf("\n%p ", *(str+4)+1);
```

**Output (System Dependent)**

```
0x7fff5fbff900 
0x7fff5fbff900 
0x7fff5fbff91e 
0x7fff5fbff942 
0x7fff5fbff929
```

---

**The Very (Very, *Very*) Long Answer**

You are incorrect in your assumption that a two dimensional array is equivalent with a pointer-to-pointer. They are similar in usage syntax-only. The following is a rough layout of how the array `a` is portrayed in memory

```
char a[5][10]

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
  -----------------------------------------
0 | o | n | e | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  -----------------------------------------
1 | t | w | o | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  -----------------------------------------
2 | t | h | r | e | e | 0 |   |   |   |   |
  -----------------------------------------
3 | f | o | u | r | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |
  -----------------------------------------
4 | f | i | v | e | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |
  -----------------------------------------
```

Note that the starting address of the second row, which is `&a[1]`, is ten bytes *past* the starting address of the first row, `&a[0]` (which is no-coincidentally the starting address of the entire array). The following demonstrates this:

```
int main()
{
    char a[5][10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

    printf("&a    = %p\n", &a);
    printf("&a[0] = %p\n", &a[0]);
    printf("a[0]  = %p\n", a[0]);
    printf("&a[1] = %p\n", &a[1]);
    printf("a[1]  = %p\n", a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
&a    = 0x7fff5fbff8e0
&a[0] = 0x7fff5fbff8e0
a[0]  = 0x7fff5fbff8e0
&a[1] = 0x7fff5fbff8ea
a[1]  = 0x7fff5fbff8ea
```

Note that the address at `a[1]` is 10 bytes (`0x0a` hex) past the beginning of the array. But why? To answer this one must understand the basics of typed-pointer arithmetic.

---

**How Does Typed-Pointer Arithmetic Work?**

In C and C++, all pointers except `void` are typed. The have a fundamental data type associated with the pointer. For example.

```
int *iptr = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

`iptr` above points to a region of memory allocated to be the size of five integers. Addressing it as we normally address arrays looks like this:

```
iptr[1] = 1;
```

but we could just as easily address it like this:

```
*(iptr+1) = 1;
```

and the result would be the same; storage of the value 1 in the second array slot (0-slot being the first). We know the dereference operator `*` allows access through an address (the address stored in the pointer). But how does `(iptr+1)` know to skip four bytes (if your `int` types are 32bit, eight bytes if they're 64bit) to access the next integer slot?

Answer: because of *typed-pointer arithmetic*. The compiler knows how wide, in bytes, the underlying *type* of the pointer is (in this case, the width of the `int` type). When you add or subtract scaler values to/from pointers, the compiler generates the appropriate code to account for this "type-width". It also works with user types as well. This is demonstrated below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Data
{
    int ival;
    float fval;
    char buffer[100];
} Data;

int main()
{
    int ivals[10];
    int *iptr = ivals;
    char str[] = "Message";
    char *pchr = str;
    Data data[2];
    Data *dptr = data;

    printf("iptr    = %p\n", iptr);
    printf("iptr+1  = %p\n", iptr+1);

    printf("pchr    = %p\n", pchr);
    printf("pchr+1  = %p\n", pchr+1);

    printf("dptr    = %p\n", dptr);
    printf("dptr+1  = %p\n", dptr+1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
iptr    = 0x7fff5fbff900
iptr+1  = 0x7fff5fbff904
pchr    = 0x7fff5fbff8f0
pchr+1  = 0x7fff5fbff8f1
dptr    = 0x7fff5fbff810
dptr+1  = 0x7fff5fbff87c
```

Notice the address difference between `iptr` and `iptr+1` is *not* one byte; it is *four* bytes (the width of an `int` on my system). Next, the width of a single `char` is demonstrated with `pchr` and `pchr+1` as one byte. Finally, our custom data type `Data` with its two pointer values, `dptr` and `dptr+1` show that it is 0x6C, or 108 bytes wide. (it could have been larger due to structure packing and field alignment, but we were fortunate with this example that it was not). That makes sense, since the structure contains two 4-byte data fields (an `int` and a `float`) and a char buffer 100 elements wide.

The reverse is also true, by the way, and is often *not* considered by even experienced C/C++ programmers. It is typed pointer *differencing*. If you have two valid pointers of a specified type within a contiguous region of valid memory:

```
int ar[10];
int *iptr1 = ar+1;
int *iptr5 = ar+5;
```

What do you suppose you get as a result from:

```
printf("%lu", iptr5 - iptr1);
```

The answer is.. `4`. Whoopee, you say. Not a big deal? *Don't you believe it*. This is *extremely* handy when using pointer arithmetic to determine the offset in a buffer of a specific element.

In summary, when you have an expression like this:

```
int ar[5];
int *iptr = ar;

iptr[1] = 1;
```

You can know it is equivalent to :

```
*(iptr+1) = 1;
```

Which, in lay-man's terms, means "Take the address held in the `iptr` variable, add 1*(width of an `int` in bytes) bytes to it, then store the value `1` in the memory dereferenced through the returned address."

Site Bar: This would also work. See if you can think of *why*

```
1[iptr] = 1;
```

---

Back to your (our) sample array, Now take a look at what happens when we refer to the same address of `a`, but through a double pointer (which is entirely incorrect and your compiler should at least warn you about the assignment):

```
char **str = a; // Error: Incompatible pointer types: char ** and char[5][10]
```

Well that doesn't work. But lets assume for a moment it did. `char **` is a pointer to a pointer-to-char. This means the variable itself holds nothing more than a pointer. It has no concept of base row width, etc. Therefore assuming you put the address of `a` in the double-pointer `str`.

```
char **str = (char **)(a); // Should NEVER do this, here for demonstration only.
char *s0 = str[0];  // what do you suppose this is?
```

Slight update to our test program:

```
int main()
{
    char a[5][10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    char **str = (char **)a;
    char *s0 = str[0];
    char *s1 = str[1];

    printf("&a    = %p\n", &a);
    printf("&a[0] = %p\n", &a[0]);
    printf("a[0]  = %p\n", a[0]);
    printf("&a[1] = %p\n", &a[1]);
    printf("a[1]  = %p\n", a[1]);

    printf("str   = %p\n", str);
    printf("s0    = %p\n", s0);
    printf("s1    = %p\n", s1);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives us the following result:

```
&a    = 0x7fff5fbff900
&a[0] = 0x7fff5fbff900
a[0]  = 0x7fff5fbff900
&a[1] = 0x7fff5fbff90a
a[1]  = 0x7fff5fbff90a
str   = 0x7fff5fbff900
s0    = 0x656e6f
s1    = 0x6f77740000
```

Well, `str` looks like it is what we want, but what is that thing in `s0` ? Why, thats the ASCII character values for letters. Which ones? A quick check of a decent [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) shows the are:

```
0x65 : e
0x6e : n
0x6f : o
```

Thats the word "one" in reverse (the reverse is caused by the endian handling of multi-byte values on my system, but I hope the problem is obvious. What about that second value:

```
0x6f : o
0x77 : w
0x74 : t
```

Yep, thats "two" . So why are we getting the *bytes* in our array as pointers?

Hmmm.. Yeah, as I said in my comment. Whomever either told you or hinted to you that double pointers and two dimensional arrays are synonymous was incorrect. Recall our hiatus into typed pointer arithmetic. Remember, this:

```
str[1]
```

and this:

```
*(str+1)
```

are synonymous. Well. what is the *type* of the `str` pointer? The type it points to is a `char` pointer. therefore, the byte count difference between this:

```
str + 0
```

and this

```
str + 1
```

will be the size of a `char*`. On my system that is 4 bytes (I have 32bit pointers). This explains why the apparent *address* in `str[1]` is the *data* four bytes into the base of our original array.

Therefore, answering your first fundamental question (yes, we *finally* got to that).

Why `str[3]` is `0xbf7f6292`

Answer: This:

```
&str[3]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
(str + 3)
```

But we know from above that `(str + 3)` is just the address stored in `str`, then adding 3x the width of the type `str` points to, which is a `char *`, in bytes to that address. Well. we know from your second `printf` what that address is:

```
0xbf7f6286
```

And we know the width of a pointer on your system is 4 bytes (32 bit pointers). Therefore...

```
0xbf7f6286 + (3 * 4)
```

or....

```
0xbf7f6286 + 0x0C = 0xbf7f6292
```

Comment: amazing answer !! The OP must have had a brilliant day to come across such an answer , i will be favourite , this question , just for this post !!!

Comment: @user2165725 , if you find any answer useful , you say so by accepting the answer

Answer (score 3):

First two printf are obviously print same address, i.e. first elememt of two-d array that is a one-d array. so there should be no doubt about that both of them are pointing to start of the array, that is a[0][0].

char **str is a pointer so when you do str[3] it internaly means (str+3) and most probably your code is running on a 32 bit machine so it will jump to 12 bytes ahead as per pointer airthematic. dont get confused with array, str is a 2-d pointer not an array.

0xbf7f6286 str[0] 
0xbf7f6292 str[3] diff is 0xc that is correct as expected.

printf("\n%p ", &str[1][56]);
printf("\n%p ", &(*(*(str+4)+1)));

Above two last statement you were trying to print because of your wrong undersanding of pointer airthematic.

I hope it would help to solve your doubt.

Comment: I have a doubt: As a is an 2D array it points to starting address of the 2D array. But, str is a pointer to a pointer. As we copied str=a so pointer variable str contains address of a and pointer variable str will be created at some location 'x'. so, when we print &str[0] it should print 'x' instead of address of a right? Please elaborate if am wrong somewhere

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[5][10]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
char **str=a;
```

Let me explain how a two start pointer works , and what is its relationship with an array , so that you can have a better chance of trying to solve the question yourself.

Conventionally double star pointers are assigned with "address" of another pointer.

Example

```
char   a =  5;
char  *b = &a;
char **c = &b;
```

so when you de-reference c one time

```
printf("\n%d",*c)
```

, you will get the value contained by 'b' , which is nothing but the address of 'a'.

When you de-reference c two times

```
printf("\n%d",**c)
```

, you will get the value of 'a' directly.

Now coming to the relationship between arrays and pointers.

An array's name is a synonym to its address , meaning the name of the array is the location of itself.

Example:

```
int array [5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
printf("\n%p",array);
printf("\n%p",&array);
printf("\n%p",&array[0]);
```

all of them will print the same address.

Hence this is an invalid pointer assignment

```
char **str=a;
```

Because **str expects an address of a pointer holding an address , but you are just passing only an address[name of array = a].

**So in short , a two star pointer , should not be used to handle  a two dimensional array.**

**This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array?rq=1) deals with handling a two dimensional array with a pointer.**

Answer (score 0):

When you say str+3 , it means str+(3*sizeof(char **)). So if size of ' char ** ' is 4bytes then
str is incremented by 12 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out a 2D array, you should be using two loops (I would suggest two 'for' loops), and have one nested inside the other.

As for the output, they're (I don't mean to state the obvious) all addresses because when you type '&' before accessing an array element, you're asking for the address of it.

Since you're setting array a equal to str, you're actually setting the pointer str to the address that array 'a' points to.

When you use [int n], the access operator, you're actually telling your computer to look 'n' address slots past where the array (or a pointer) actually points to. Thus why it's 16 more than the top two.

The last two look like Hex, I'm not entirely sure about those last two output lines.