# Multiplying 2 matrices using pointers

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, matrix

so I am trying to figure out how to multiply 2 matrices using pointers.  It successfully works the way it is now, but instead of using conventional array access methods, I would like to learn the use of pointers.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/* Routines called. */
int loadMatrixFromFile(char *filename, int *data);
void showMatrix(int *data, int len);
int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int length);
int matrixA[5][5];
int matrixB[5][5];
int matrixC[5][5];
void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]);

int main(){
    int len, data[1000];
    len = loadMatrixFromFile("Numbers.txt", data);
    showMatrix(data, len);
    makeIdent(matrixB,len);
    multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);
}

int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int len){
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix B is: \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
           for(j=0;j<5;j++){
                 if(i==j){
                         matrixB[i][j]=1;
                         printf("%d ",matrixB[i][j]);
                 }
                 else{
                     matrixB[i][j]=0;
                     printf("%d ",matrixB[i][j]);
                 }
           }
           printf("\n");
     }
    return matrixB[i][j];
     printf("\n");
}
int loadMatrixFromFile(char *filename, int *data){
    FILE *in;
    int len;
    int j;
    in = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        printf("Could not find file: %s \n", filename);
    }
    else {
        printf("Reading numbers...\n");
        fscanf(in, "%d", &len);
        printf("reading %d numbers from file %s ....\n", len, filename);
        for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
            fscanf(in, "%d", data + j);
        }
        fclose(in);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                matrixA[i][j] = *(data + i*5 + j);
        }
    }
    return len;
}
void showMatrix(int *data, int len){
    int j;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Showing %d numbers from data array....\n", len);
    printf("Matrix A is: \n");
    for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
        printf("%d ", *(data + j));
        count++;
        if(count % 5 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]){
     int i, n, j;
     int count = 0;

     printf("\n");
     printf("Matrix A x Matrix B is: \n");
     for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
            for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
                matrixC[i][j] = 0;
                matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][j]*matrixB[i][j];
                printf("%d ",matrixC[i][j]);
                count++;
                if(count % 5 == 0){
                printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][j]*matrixB[i][j]` is *not* how matrix multiplication works!

Comment: I do not see any benefit or use of pointers in this application. It will only complicate things. Following link explains how you can represent 2D matrix in terms of pointers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array

Comment: @Martin R I had originally done matrixC[i][n] += matrixA[i][j]*matrixB[j][n], but it gave me a different matrix than the one I was looking for.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: `for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) { matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][k]*matrixB[k][j]; }`

Comment: Decide which language you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Well your algorithm for matrix multiplication is completely wrong.

You say 'I want to learn how to do it with pointers', but here's the thing, **you're already are doing it with pointers**.

In this code

```
void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]){
```

the variables `matrixA`, `matrixB` and `matrixC` are pointers. In C++ it's impossible to have an array for a function parameter. It automatically gets converted to a pointer. It's also true that the syntax for accessing an array is identical to the syntax for accessing a pointer.

If you want to make it explicit that you are using pointers then rewrite your code like this

```
void multiplyMatrices(int (*matrixA)[5], int (*matrixB)[5],int (*matrixC)[5]){
```

Now you can see that `matrixA`, `matrixB` and `matrixC` pointers to arrays of 5 integers. You don't have to make any other changes. And in fact this change is exactly what the compiler does when you try to use an array as a function parameter.

Here's a good looking link that explains [how pointers and arrays compare](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/). The link talks about C, but the rules are the same in C++. Have a read it will probably help you understand better than I can.

Comment: Awesome link, it is much appreciated this is exactly what I needed to learn to use pointers.  Best tutorial I have seen so far.