# C++ Passing pointer to multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

So I have a pointer to a 2D array like so:

```
int board[3][5] = { 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 34, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 223, 923 };
int* ptr[sizeof(board[0]) / sizeof(board[0][0])] = board;
```

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array). But for some reason I'm getting the error:

> IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate
>   object

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: This question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign pointer to the first element of the array like below

```
int (*ptr)[5] = board;
```

**Note:** Column size [5] in the pointer declaration should be equal to the original 2 dimension array column size [5]. 
      Declaring row size [3] is optional.

```
int main() {

    int board[3][5] = { 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 34, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 223, 923 };

    /*
    // 3 Rows 5 Columns Matrix
       int board[3][5] = { {3, 5, 2, 2, 1 },
                           {3, 4, 34, 2, 2 },
                           {3, 4, 3, 223, 923}
                         };
   */

   // Assign pointer to the first element of the array
   int (*ptr)[5] = board;

   for(int i=0; i< (3*5); i++) {
       std::cout<<(*ptr)[i]<<std::endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is not the same as an array of pointers. You cannot directly convert one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to put () around the *ptr. I have no idea how this fixes it but now I can do `ptr[1][2]`.