# Pointer to 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I need to get access to 2 dimensional array that referenced from pointer to struct but I cannot
see the values stored in this array.
I used method thta was proposed here to get access via pointer to 2D Array ( as described here  [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array) )
the structure encapsulated in shred memory erea between 2 processes.
the struct contains 2D array of floats.
altoght there are values stored in the first array of the 2D array , the value read in function foo is 0 .
is this is the right access mode ? 
is the difference is due to the fact that the access is via double pointer mechanism ? ( using the Arrow notation )

```
typedef struct
{
    float32 Position[3];    
    float32 MODE[4];
    float32 GeneralInfo;
    float32 COLOR [8][3];
} tsInputData;

typedef float32 array_of_3_float32[3];

array_of_3_float32 *p_Color;
float32* p_Position;
float32* p_Mode;
float32* p_GeneralInfo;

void Init_Host(void* InData)
{
    pData = (tsInputData*)InData;

    p_Position = pData->Position;
    p_Mode = pData->MODE;
    p_GeneralInfo = &(pData->GeneralInfo);
    p_Color = pData->COLOR;
}

int foo()
{
    float32 var = p_Color[0][0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you did it is correct, though a bit cumbersome. You can define two-dimensional array pointers like this:

```
float32 (*p_Color)[3]; // pointer to array of blocks of three floats each
```

In C89 and above you are also allowed to use runtime variables for the sizes:

```
size_t num_cols;
float32 (*p_Color)[num_cols];
```

Comment: It should be "C99 and above", I think.

Comment: Variable-length arrays were mandatory in C 1999. C 2011 made them optional.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. pointer to 2D array

```
float data[8][3] = { {1.2, 2.3, 4.5},{1.25, 1.5, 1.75}};
float (*a_8_3)[8][3] = &data;//pointer to float [8][3]
float (*a_3)[3] = data;      //pointer to float [3]
printf("%f\n", (*a_8_3)[1][2]);//1.75
printf("%f\n", a_3[1][1]);     //1.5
```