# How to convert a (long *) to a 2 dimensional array of longs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code in C where `G` is a global variable:

```
long *G;

int function(long matrix[35][10]){
    G=&matrix[0][0];
}
```

Once I store the address of `matrix[0][0]` in `G`, I can access all the elements of `matrix` like so:

```
G[0]=...
G[1]=...
.
.
.
G[349]=...
```

I want to be able to access all of these elements similar to how I can with `matrix`, by using the two square brackets from inside of another function. How would I be able to do that? That is, how can I tell the compiler that the offset for the second dimension in this 2 dimensional array is 10?

---

I did look at this answer:
[Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)
, but I'm not sure if the user asked the exact same thing. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It is the same question

Comment: @Dabo So if I follow the answer to that question, a 64 bit value will basically be allocated for my global variable right? Just making sure

Comment: `long *G` is just a pointer, if `sizeof` pointer on your machine is `8` then yes, it will have 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
long (*array)[10] = (long(*)[10])G;
```

`array` is a pointer to an array of 10 `long`s.

Comment: Just to make sure, only 64 bits are allocated for `array` right? The fact that there is a 3 in front of it, makes me think three longs are allocated

Comment: It depends on the system, `sizeof(long*)` will be allocated for `array`.

Comment: Or since he wants to use `G` itself like that, rather just declare `G` as `long (* G)[10];` and assign `matrix` to it directly, like `G = matrix;`.

Answer (score -2):

Make G a poiter to pointer.

```
long **G;
```

Still you will not be able to access directly by G[i] i goes from 0 to 349.

But one easy thing that you can do is converting a number to 2 subscripts.

for example:

```
G[349] is actually G[34][9].
```

Hence formula is 
if you want

```
G[k]
```

then access it like this:

```
G[k/10][k%10];
```

This is for this particular case.

For general case,
the formula to convert 1 subscript to 2 subscripts is:

```
G[k] is equivalent to G[k/NO_OF_COLUMNS][k%NO_OF_COLUMNS];
```

Comment: this does not work. pointers and arrays are not the same. reading G[34] will get an element from the data buffer of the array and will try to dereference it that obviously causes an access violation