# Create a pointer to a 3-dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I've looked at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array), but its not working.

Externally, in Filter.h I have

```
struct test{
    unsigned char arr[3][8192][8192];
}
```

I have one of these structs initialized, and my code works properly if I use:

```
initialized_test_struct -> arr[2][54][343]
```

However, I want to cache a pointer to this array:

```
unsigned char (*new_ptr)[8192][8192] = &(initialized_test_struct -> arr)
assert initialized_test_struct -> arr[2][54][343] == new_ptr[2][54][343]
```

But when I try this, I get:

> cannot convert ‘unsigned char (*)[3][8192][8192]’ to ‘unsigned char (*)[8192][8192]’ in initialization

When I try:

```
unsigned char (*colors)[3][8192][8192] = &(input -> color);
```

I get the wrong data type (when being used):

> error: invalid operands of types ‘unsigned char [8192]’ and ‘char’ to binary ‘operator*’

How can I pull this off?

Comment: You should try the typedef approach proposed at the link you posted.

Comment: You should try the `typedef` approach proposed at the link you posted. `typedef unsigned char array_of_8192x8192_uchar_t[8192][8192]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test{
    unsigned char arr[3][8192][8192];
};

int main()
{
    test initialized_test_struct;
    unsigned char (*new_ptr)[8192][8192] = initialized_test_struct.arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever you use an array variable in an expression it is converted to a pointer to the type of the array elements. For example,

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int* b = a; // this is ok
```

However, if we do

```
int a[2][1] = {{1}, {2}};
int* b = a; // this will fail, rhs has type int(*)[1], not int*
```

We would have to do

```
int a[2][1] = {{1}, {2}};
int (*b)[1] = a; // OK!
```

If you have a C++11-compatible compiler, you could simply do

```
auto new_ptr =  initialized_test_struct.arr;
```

The compiler takes care of the type-deduction for you and replaces auto with the correct type.

Comment: I just saw your answer. This auto new_ptr =  initialized_test_struct.arr is basically what I did!

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char (*new_ptr)[8192][8192] = &(initialized_test_struct -> arr);
```

should be

```
unsigned char new_ptr[3][8192][8192] = initialized_test_struct -> arr;
```

But this is really bad C++, this is better if you use C++11:

```
auto new_ptr = initialized_test_struct -> arr;
```

And I don't know about the specifics of your problem, but a class like a `std::vector` could give you better usability and be easier to deal with.

By the way, an array is a pointer already, this is why you don't have to use `&`. You could want to create a pointer to that array (why?), in that case use:

```
auto *new_ptr = &initialized_test_struct -> arr;
```

and:

```
unsigned char *new_ptr[3][8192][8192] = &initialized_test_struct -> arr;
```

and:

```
assert initialized_test_struct -> arr[2][54][343] == (*new_ptr)[2][54][343]
```

Comment: This didn't work. I added c++11 to my flags, and I'm not getting any more errors, but it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Additionally, this is unclear: 

"auto *new_ptr = &initialized_test_struct -> arr;"
and:
"unsigned char *new_ptr[3][8192][8192] = &initialized_test_struct -> arr;" have an inherent conflict?

Comment: I think it's the `->arr` that's the error , instead of `.arr`

Comment: -> arr would be dereferencing a pointer, and  &initialized_test_struct  is a pointer to the struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto new_ptr = initialized_test_struct -> arr;
```

Was the only thing that I could get to work. In order for this to work, I also had to add the -std=c++11 flag, as it is part of c++11