# Setting the starting memory address of a 2d array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array of structures, like so:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
    float baz;
};
```

I'm actually learning about OS development right now, and one thing I'm trying to do is created a 2d array of these structures with the dimensions 80x25:

```
struct foo foobar[80][25];
```

Though I need to set it to the address `0xb8000`, since this is where the video memory starts. Is there any way I can specify the address in which my array starts?

So far I have tried doing this:

```
struct foo foobar[80][25];
*foobar = (struct foo) 0xb8000;
```

But this doesn't work. Edit: also, is doing something like this legal and/or possible to the c99 standard?

Comment: `foo = (struct foo *) 0xb8000;`

Comment: @kaylum Good catch, will edit that now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare array at a specific location, but you can use a pointer:

```
struct foo *x;
x = (struct foo*)0xb8000;
```

This should work, but probably the operating system will complain if you tried that from a normal program, unless it is DOS or something like that.

Comment: Bear in mind that OP wants to access the variable as a two dimensional array. Does your solution allow that?

Comment: Hmm, okay. How would I go around doing the equivalent of x[10][15] with the pointer? `x[10 + 15 * buffer_width];`?

Comment: The array thing cannot be done at all, unless your compiler/linker provides a nonstandard way.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) Also to clarify, where I put 10 + 15, which one is the row and which one is the column, and which of those are x,y? I always get confused about that.

Comment: @CecilioPardo That's not quite true. Have a look at this for example: [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: The number with the * is the row (Y). The other one is the column (X).

Comment: @kaylum What's not true, and why?

Comment: @CecilioPardo "The array thing cannot be done at all". I thought you mean that it is not possible to declare a pointer to a multi dimensional array such that the pointer can then be dereferenced using multiple array indexes. That is possible and would fit more naturally for what the OP wants to do rather than flattening the array to one dimension.

Comment: @kaylum No, I meant you cannot declare an array and tell the compiler to put it at a precise location in memory. Sorry for the mixup.