# c allocating space for a 2d array of pointers in a loop

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, allocation

I have a rather large program that requires me to use pointers to 2 dimensional arrays. I'm having a difficult time allocating space for the arrays.

I've already tried allocating the space at the time of declaration but I ran into a million road blocks.

I found code here: [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)

I have a 2D array of pointers to an array `other_arrays`

I have this:

```
    static double other_arrays[51][1];
    double (*SumH)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*WeightIH)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*Hidden)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*SumO)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*WeightHO)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*Output)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*DeltaWeightIH)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    double (*DeltaWeightHO)[51][1] = &other_arrays;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      for (j = 0; j < 51; j++){
        SumH[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        WeightIH[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        Hidden[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        SumO[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        WeightHO[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        Output[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        DeltaWeightIH[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        DeltaWeightHO[j][i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
      }
    }
```

When I compile I get: `error: array type 'double [1]' is not assignable`

I've tried some things I've found online such as `SumH[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));`

But then I get: `error: array type 'double [51][1]' is not assignable`

Or something like this yields the same error:

```
  for (j = 0; j < 51; j++){
    SumH[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    WeightIH[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    Hidden[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    SumO[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    WeightHO[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    Output[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    DeltaWeightIH[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    DeltaWeightHO[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
  }
```

**SOLUTION**

I didn't cast `malloc`

```
    *SumH[j][i] = *(double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Do not cast `malloc()` to the target type.

Comment: @iharob I'm getting a bus error at a 3D allocation `*Input[i][j][k] = *(double *)malloc(sizeof(double));` i = 20 j = 2 k = 51

Comment: @iharob This is probably the most cited sentence for c-tagged questions at SO. However, common sense is that it is a matter of style. Insisting that it is a Bad Thing[tm] to cast the return value of malloc() is a bit too dogmatic in my eyes.

Comment: Are you trying to end up with an array of pointers or a pointer to an array?

Comment: @iharob am I running out of memory?

Comment: @iharob I guess I'm overflowing, but I'm not going past the bounds of the array of pointers

Comment: @immibis array of pointers

Comment: @kendallweihe You should think about an array of size one. The only useful thing would be if you need to pass it as a parameter sometimes, in this case it seems pointless.

Comment: your outer loop range is 0-1, but your second dimension is 1 not 2. Why is it 1, BTW?

Comment: Suggestion: this isn't really an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  You have the same problem 8 times in a row.  Two of the arrays would be sufficient to demonstrate your problem.  I'm trying to work out the significance of the multiple initializations with `&other_arrays`.  Since all 8 arrays are pointing at the same space, the first 7 arrays worth of allocations are being leaked as the assignments for the last array overwrites the others, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate 2d arrays:

```
    /* allocate 2d arrays */
    double (*SumH)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*WeightIH)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*Hidden)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*SumO)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*WeightHO)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*Output)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*DeltaWeightIH)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*DeltaWeightHO)[51][1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    /* ... */
    free(DeltaWeightHO);
    free(DeltaWeightIH);
    free(Output);
    free(WeightHO);
    free(SumO);
    free(Hidden);
    free(WeightIH);
    free(SumH);
```

Usage would be ... (*SumH)[j][i] ...

I doubt this is want you wanted.
To allocate pointers to the first row of 2d arrays:

```
    /* allocate pointers to first row of 2d arrays */
    double (*SumH)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*WeightIH)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*Hidden)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*SumO)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*WeightHO)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*Output)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*DeltaWeightIH)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
    double (*DeltaWeightHO)[1] = malloc(51*1*sizeof(double));
```

Usage would be ... SumH[j][i] ...

To allocate array of pointers to rows

```
    /* allocate array of pointers to rows */
    double (*SumH[51])[1];
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(SumH)/sizeof(SumH[0]); i++)
        SumH[i] = malloc(1*sizeof(double));
```

Usage would be ... SumH[j][i] ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want pointers to arrays and want to initialize them, then you should be doing things much more simply:

```
double (*SumH)[5][2] = malloc(sizeof(*SumH));
double (*WeightIH)[5][2] = malloc(sizeof(*WeightIH));
```

Now you can use:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        (*SumH)[i][j] = k;
        (*WeightIH)[i][j] = k++;
    }
}
```

Note that an array dimension of `[1]` is close to pointless.

FWIW, [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) gives the following code a clean bill of health:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double (*SumH)[5][2] = malloc(sizeof(*SumH));
    double (*WeightIH)[5][2] = malloc(sizeof(*WeightIH));


    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        (*SumH)[i][j] = k;
        (*WeightIH)[i][j] = k++;
    }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        printf("[%f, %f]", (*SumH)[i][j], (*WeightIH)[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
    }

    free(SumH);
    free(WeightIH);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is not very exciting:

```
[0.000000, 0.000000][1.000000, 1.000000]
[2.000000, 2.000000][3.000000, 3.000000]
[4.000000, 4.000000][5.000000, 5.000000]
[6.000000, 6.000000][7.000000, 7.000000]
[8.000000, 8.000000][9.000000, 9.000000]
```