# Access multidimensional array passed to function

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to access a multidimensional Array that is passed via pointer. I followed the question here ([Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array)) to create my array and a pointer to it. I could even pass the pointer to the function, but I can't use the pointer to access the array values. What's the correct way to access the values inside the function.

main.cpp:

```
MyArrayGenerator theArrGen = MyArrayGenerator();
const int size = 9;
int generatorArray[size][size][10];

theArrGen.generateArray(size, generatorArray[size][size+1]);
```

The method in my class:

```
void MyArrayGenerator::generateArray(int size,int* pointerToMultiDimArr)
{
    int height = size + 1;
    // this ptr points to the array address
    int* ptr = pointerToMultiDimArr;
    // not working:
    ptr[1][1][1] = 123;
}
```

this throws the compiler error https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fhexbxk9.aspx wich means that the pointer is not declared as array.

I guess my method argument needs to change since it wants a pointer and does not know that it will be an array. My question is: How should the method argument look like and how do I access the array in my method after that. Later on I want the user to input the size of the multidimensional array and

```
    const int size = 9;
```

is just a placeholder

Comment: Why have you tagged this as *C*?

Comment: sorry thought this problem would be interchangeable between the two. Deleted the C tag.

Comment: The language with classes is C++, not C. And there is no multidimensional array. A pointer is not even a 1D array.

Comment: When passing a pointer to a multi-dimensional array to a function, the receiving function only gets a pointer to the first element.  All information about the dimensions is lost.  You will have to calculate the index yourself or use the correct syntax for passing an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pointer notation to access elements! Here is an example to access and use 2d array's pointer this program prints transpose of a matrix

```
#include<iostream>
int **arr_input(int row, int col)
{
    int **arr;
    arr = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)        //array size
    {
        *(arr + i) = new int[col];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cin >> *(*(arr + i) + j);
        }
    }   //input array
    return arr;
}


void transpose(int**arr, int row, int col)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout << *(*(arr + j) + i) << "  ";      //pointer notation//
        }   
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void main(){
          int row ,col,**ptr1;
        cout << "Enter size of Square Matrix: ";    cin >> row; col = row;
        cout << "\n\tEnter the elements of Matrix\n";
        ptr1 = arr_input(row, col);    //calling array input function
        cout << "\nAdress of pointer is " << ptr1<<endl;
        transpose(ptr1, row, col);  //calling transpose function
        system("pause");
   }
```

Comment: The problem is that the receiving function has no idea on the capacities of the dimensions.  The evaluation of `arr[1][2][1]` is meaningless without the capacities of the dimensions.  The second dimension may have 5 elements, it may have 512.

Comment: thanks for actually trying to answer and not just blaming :). Does this mean If I want to have a multidimensional array I need a pointer to a pointer wich then points to the array. I will also need a for loop to create the multi dimensional array (the arr_input method)? Or is it possible to create the array via `int myArr[3][3][3];`.