# Generate random numbers with Array

Tags: arrays, c, random

I am learning C and I keep mixing up array and matrix. and I can't seem to understand where I am doing wrong with my code. I have made 2 different version of it and the only feedback I am getting is, I have mixed array with matrix.

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand exactly where I went wrong, since I am not getting anywhere with my prof and his explanation about it. (Sorry in advanced)

This is the first code,  But both of them are really similar.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int array[100];
    int max = 0, min = 1;
    int fro;

    fro = (int)time(NULL);
    srand(fro);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % (400 + 1 - 100) + 100;
        if (array[i] <= min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
        if (array[i] >= max)
            max = array[i];
    }
     
    printf("Array\n");
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            printf(" %i ", array[row * 10 + col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

This is another version, but I got similar feedback as the first one.
I am mixing up array and matrix..

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int tal[10][10];
    int array[100];
    int max = 0, min = 1;
    int fro;

    fro = (int)time(NULL);
    srand(fro);

    // Version 3 of the array slump generation

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        //printf("Yttre loop row %i\n", row);
        
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) { // row = 1, col = 0
            tal[row][col] = rand() % (400 + 1 - 100) + 100;
            // printf("tal[%i][%i] = %i\n", row, col, tal[row][col]);

            // Get max
            if (tal[row][col] >= max) {
                max = tal[row][col];
            }
            // Get min
            if (tal[row][col] <= min) {
                min = tal[row][col];
            }
            // printf("tal[%i][%i] = %i\n", row, col, tal[row][col]);
        }
    }
    
    // Printar ut hela matrisen i row-major order
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            printf(" %i ", tal[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I mean both of them works and I think I am using array :/
We haven't even gone trough matrix yet...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe your understanding of array and matrix.

Comment: `int min = 1;` looks strange.  `array[i] <= min` will never be true.  Maybe start with `min = 1000;` or `min = INT_MAX;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of a matrix is not an `ISO C` concept. However, you can use an array to denote a matrix by imposing imposing additional linear algebra constraints. There are [several linear algebra libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_linear_algebra_libraries) for C. However, be prepared for some people use the term *matrix* loosely to mean any two-dimensional array, because they look similar in most presentations.

Your first example is an `int array[100]` which stores [array 100 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+a%5B100%5D). You then access it by 10 `row` and 10 `col`; since 10 * 10 = 100 <= 100 that you've reserved for it, this is entirely valid. One might prefer this representation because it is explicitly [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4059363/2472827), but has no way for the compiler to bounds-check.

Your second example is `int tal[10][10]`, which is [array 10 of array 10 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+tal%5B10%5D%5B10%5D), [all in the same block of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36647286/2472827). It's the same 100-element array, but accessed differently, as you've done. This is also valid, and I think more what your teacher was asking.

The one you treat more like a matrix will be more like a matrix.