# Initializing a 2D Array within a function, calling by pointer. Getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

The objective of this program is of right now to set each array variable of the 2D array,

**char mass_data_shift[9][9];**  equal to 'T' . Which should equal 100 Ts overall.

This is done by calling a void function with this 2D array address as an argument. Calling it by a pointer to then be initialized in a loop.

Inside the loop is were the 2D array should be set to T.

***mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';**

However..... the program results in:

- (Most Often) A Segmentation Fault after trying to initialize ***mass_data[4][2]**
- (Sometimes) A Segmentation Fault after the program successfully(?) runs.
- (Sometimes) The program successfully runs.

Meaning the program, somewhere, is writing out of bounds. Any help would be appreciated in both making the program run without a segmentation fault and/or fixing other mistakes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void mass_data_define(char (*mass_data)[9][9]){

  int mass_data_counter;
  int mass_data_counter_two = 0;

  for (mass_data_counter=0;mass_data_counter<9;mass_data_counter++){
    do {    
      std::cout << "|Array #1   " << mass_data_counter
                << "   :::   |Array #2    " << mass_data_counter_two 
                << std::endl;

      *mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';

      std::cout << *mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two];

      mass_data_counter_two++;
      std::cout << "---------End of Counter 2 Init Code----------" << std::endl;
    } while (mass_data_counter_two < 9);

    mass_data_counter_two = 0;
  }
}

int main()
{
    char mass_data_shift[9][9];

    mass_data_define(&mass_data_shift);

    std::cout << "-END-" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Final Edit: The main cause was solved by szym below. Sorry about the whitespaces and missing iostream , was a formatting issue when I made the post. Also changed the loop to fit the array length as suggested below.

Comment: You only have a maximum of 81 spaces.  An array of N is indexed by 0..N-1.  It seems to me you think that the array is sized to be N+1 because you say your 9x9 array holds 100 elements.  It only holds 81.

Comment: Looks like you're looping from 0 to 9. Your array only supports 0 to 8.

Comment: Alright, after I changed the looping to go from 0-8 rather then 0-9 I still get a segmentation fault. Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';
```

Should be

```
(*mass_data)[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';
```

Naturally, same goes for the line:

```
std::cout << *mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two]
```

But really this pointer type is not necessary to pass array by reference in C/C++.

You should instead declare:

```
void mass_data_define(char mass_data[9][9]) {
    // To read:
    char z = mass_data[3][6];
    // To write:
    mass_data[2][1] = 'C';
}

// elsewhere
char my_mass_data[9][9];
mass_data_define(my_mass_data);
```

Comment: What exactly is `*mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two]` here? Is it some arbitrary address that it is pointing to?

Comment: Ah, yes I will change it to no longer use a pointer. However changing it from *mass_data[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';                 to (*mass_data)[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';
still didn't fix the segmentation fault, when the pointer is kept.

Comment: Did you update both cases of using `*mass_data[x][y]` instead of the correct `(*mass_data)[x][y]`? I updated the answer.

Comment: Nope! Fixed now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Here's a one-line fix to your code so may continue to use a pointer and still *not* get a segmentation fault:

```
        (*mass_data)[mass_data_counter][mass_data_counter_two] = 'T';
```

Long Answer: Read [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array).

For an in-depth understanding of how to pointers to access multi-dimensional arrays, read [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwu4iGPfYEufb3VUd3BjTkd5cU0/view?usp=sharing).