# (2D int array pointer to pointer) why is there a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the elements of a 2D array but I keep getting a segmentation fault (I use my own printing function so i don't use printf)

the code:

(this is the main)

```
int main()
{

  int zArr[3][4]={1, 2, 3, 4};
  int *zPtr = *zArr;
  print2dArray(&zPtr, 3, 4);

  return 0;
}
```

(this is the function)

```
void print2dArray(int **arr, int rows, int cols) 
{
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  for(a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
    for(b = 0; b < cols; b++) {
      putNum(arr[a][b]);
    }
  }
}
```

(this is the output)

```
1
2
3
4
segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Comment: `int zArr[3][4]` is not `int**`.

Comment: On this post you will find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array