# c++: function arg char** is not the same as char*[]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arguments

I am using g++.  I am using code that had a `main(int,char**)`, renamed so I can call it.  I looked at [Should I use char** argv or char* argv[] in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779910/should-i-use-char-argv-or-char-argv-in-c), where `char**` is said to be equivalent to `char* []`.  This does not appear to be true in c++ function calls.  For example:

```
void f1(char** p){;}

void f2(char* p[]){

   f1(p);

 //...`

}
```

fails with the compiler complaining "cannot convert `char (*)[]` to `char**`..."  The references I look to say that arrays are converted to pointers for the call, but this does not seem to be the case as:

```
void f3(char* [] p);

char caa[16][16];  
f3(caa);
```

also fails.   I had assumed that as long as the levels of indirection were the same (e.g. `char*** ptr` and `char[][][] carray` ) the types were interchangeable.

Can someone provide a reference I can review that clarifies these issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This still holds true in C++. If your compiler complains as you describe for your first case, it is non-conformant.

To explain your second case, it is important to understand what actually happens. An expression of array type is implicitly convertible to a corresponding pointer type, i.e.: `T[n]` -> `T*`. However, if `T` itself is an array, this case isn't treated specially, and array-to-pointer decay *does not propagate*. So `T*[n]` decays to `T**`, but `T[x][y]` will only decay to `T[y]*`, and no further.

From implementation perspective this makes sense, because decaying further, if allowed, would give `T**`, which is pointer to pointer; whereas 2D C arrays aren't implemented as jagged arrays (i.e. array of pointers to arrays) - they form a single contiguous memory block. So, there's no `T*` "inside" the array to take an address of to give you a `T**`. For the allowed cases, a typical implementation simply takes the address of the array as a whole and converts it to type of pointer to single element (when underlying pointer representation is the same for all types, as is usually the case, this convertion is a no-op at run time).

The normative reference here is ISO C++03, 4.2[conv.array]/1:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping for a URL.  I don't really understand what you are saying.  Is char** equiv to char* []?  It seems to me:
char c;
char* cp = &c;
`char** cpp = &cp;`
char* cparray[128];
cparray and cpp are not equivalent.  Isn't &T[n] -> T* ?  The issue I am trying to address is the conversions taking place in function call arguments.  The reference I am using right now is O'Reilly C++ in a Nutshell.  Is "ISO C++03, 4.2[conv.array]" available on the web, or is it a document that must be ordered from a publisher?

Comment: It is equivalent, but _only_ in function declarations, when applied to argument types. Also, `char*[]` is implicitly convertible to `char**`, but `char[][]` is not.

Comment: ISO C++ is the specification for the C++ language standard - in other words, the primary document which defines exact syntax and semantics of the C++ language. It is not legally available for free, though a PDF can be purchased for $30 here: http://www.techstreet.com/cgi-bin/basket?action=add&item_id=3626517

Comment: @cvsdave, In particular, compare `*(int(*)[1])0` with `*(int**)0`. The first practically doesn't crash, because dereferencing an array pointer will not read anything from memory - it just passes the address through and only changes the type. Dereferencing the `int**` pointer, however, will read an `int*` from a specific address (null pointer address here, which will likely crash). So even when the "level of indirections" seem to be equal - they *mean* very different things for arrays and for pointers :)

Comment: @cvsdave, to complement pavel's nice answer with some experiments on the level of indirections, you could have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274865/pointer-question-in-c/274943#274943

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void f2(char* p[]){
> ```
>
> the compiler complaining "`cannot convert char (*)[] to char**...`"

Strange.  `char(*)[]` is a **pointer to array of chars**,  but in your code snippet the function has `char *p[]` argument, what means **array of pointers to char**!  These types are indeed different (because array elements have different sizes), let alone your code snippet perfectly compiles.  You really have misspelled something.

*Sherlock Holmes mode*: or is there a typedef involved? ;-)

```
void f1(char** p){;}

typedef char type[];
void f2(type * p){
   f1(p);
}
```

This really doesn't compile and yields the error you referred to.

Comment: void f4(char* [16]){;}
int main*int argc, char** argv){
char caa[16][16];
f4(caa);
}
yields:
a.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
a.cpp:4: error: cannot convert `char (*)[16]' to `char**' for argument `1' to `void f4(char**)'
g++ 3.4.5 run on Redhat 5 and Win XP
This is what puzzles me.

Comment: Well, Pavel Minaev has explained above that `char caa[16][16]` during function call is converted to `char (*caa)[16]`.  This means, `*caa` denotes the *array* of characters and is equal to `caa`.  What you want is converting it to `(char *)caa[16]`, or, differently, `char *caa[16]`, which can't be done due to the reasons I explained in my post.