# How to pass in a 3D array with set x index as a 2D array?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, reinterpret-cast, function-declaration

I have a 3D array `arr[x][y][z]`, where at a given point x is a constant, and I want to pass in `are[const][y][z]` as a 2D pointer. The following lines are how I attempted to do so:

```
double tmpMatrix[msize][msize][msize];<- array declaration

...

test(msize, (double*)(tmpMatrix[i]));<- function calling

...

void test(int msize, double * m) <- function which takes in 2D arrays
```

This is my first question on stack overflow, if there are any useful tips you could provide me, it would be much appreciated. Any unnecessary hate will be ignored.

Comment: First, it's not a 3D array, it's an array of arrays of arrays. That matters. Thus `tmpMatrix[i]` will give an array of arrays. C- style casting to a double pointer is not correct. You should use the proper array type, or even `std::array` preferably.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I treat an array like a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676402/why-cant-i-treat-an-array-like-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. When you say proper array type, could you please elaborate or provide any links to demonstrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wrong comment to this function declaration

```
void test(int msize, double * m) <- function which takes in 2D arrays
```

Neither parameter of the function is declared as a two dimensional array or a pointer to a two-dimensional array.

It seems you mean

```
void test(int n, double ( * m )[msize][msize] ); <- function which takes in 2D arrays.
```

Where `msize` - is a compile-time constant.

Or if you want to pass a pointer to a two-dimensional array as a pointer to one dimensional array then you have to write

```
test( ( msize - x ) * msize * msize, reinterpret_cast<double *>( tmpMatrix + x ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program I changed the order of the parameter declarations in the function test.

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t msize = 3;

void test( double *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / ( msize * msize ); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < msize; j++ )
        {
            for ( size_t k = 0; k < msize; k++ )
            {
                std::cout << a[i * msize * msize + j * msize + k] << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    double a[msize][msize][msize] =
    {
        {
            { 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 },
            { 4.1, 5.1, 6.1 },
            { 7.1, 8.1, 9.1 }
        },
        {
            { 1.2, 2.2, 3.2 },
            { 4.2, 5.2, 6.2 },
            { 7.2, 8.2, 9.2 }
        },
        {
            { 1.3, 2.3, 3.3 },
            { 4.3, 5.3, 6.3 },
            { 7.3, 8.3, 9.3 }
        },
    };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < msize; i++ )
    {
        test( reinterpret_cast<double *>( a + i ), ( msize - i ) * msize * msize );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1.1 2.1 3.1 
4.1 5.1 6.1 
7.1 8.1 9.1 

1.2 2.2 3.2 
4.2 5.2 6.2 
7.2 8.2 9.2 

1.3 2.3 3.3 
4.3 5.3 6.3 
7.3 8.3 9.3 


1.2 2.2 3.2 
4.2 5.2 6.2 
7.2 8.2 9.2 

1.3 2.3 3.3 
4.3 5.3 6.3 
7.3 8.3 9.3 


1.3 2.3 3.3 
4.3 5.3 6.3 
7.3 8.3 9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

void test(int msize, double * m), here m is a pointer to double(acts kind of array while using), doesnt represent a 2D array.
So you can do access the 2D array elements by explicitly doing address manipulation to traverse the elements or you can change the function to recieve a 2D array as a pointer to Array `double (*m)[Z]` and you can traverse the 2D array as a series of 1D arrays.
You can refer answer at [Create a pointer to two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array) and [what is `int *userMask[3][4]` pointing to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274865/what-is-int-usermask34-pointing-to/274943#274943)

Comment: No, `m` is not an array. It is a pointer to a double.